# Printing a Checkerboard - Code compiles but not outputting what I want

Tags: java

My code compiles, but it's not outputting what I want.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Checkerboard {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num, col;
        //Scanner for input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Get input
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        num = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the same number: ");
        col = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int n = 0; n < num; n++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

It is outputting the pattern
(if N, C = 5)

```
* * * * * 
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
```

What I want is

```
 * * * * * 
* * * * *
 * * * * * 
* * * * * 
 * * * * *
```

Any tips on how I could output what I want?

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger and run your code step by step...

Comment: There is nothing in your code that make a space on odd lines

Comment: In fact, I ran your code and it outputted it perfectly fine..... I ran it using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: What do you use as an IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are adding the space at the end of the line instead of at the beginning of the next line, and anyway, you only want to add the space not on each line, but only any other line.

```
    for (int n = 0; n < num; n++) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: @GiannaCaruso fixed now

Answer (score 4):

Insert

```
if(n%2==0){
  System.out.print(" ");
```

before the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your inside `for` loop to

```
   if(n%2==0){
      System.out.print(" *");
     } else {
      System.out.print("* ");
   }
```

Out put:

```
  * * * * * 
 * * * * *  
  * * * * * 
 * * * * *  
  * * * * *
```

Comment: that's an interesting looking output

Comment: @Zhuinden not really.

Answer (score 0):

change inside for loop:

```
  if(n%2==0){
          System.out.print(" *");
         } else {
          System.out.print("* ");
       }
```